# How do you multiply $x < y$ to get $1/x > 1/y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I'm stuck on this part. I only know that I'd get $x/x = 1$ and $y/y = 1$, which doesn't fit the inequality.

Rudin, page 8, Proposition 1.18e

Comment: Why not $(xy)^{-1}$?

Comment: divide both sides by xy

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Rudin provides a proof for the proposition. Is there something you don't understand in it?

Comment: I just didn't know how got from x < y to 1/x > 1/y, my skills are very limited in algebra. I understand the part that the greater y is the smaller the fraction 1/y is, same for x.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, this is not correct. Because, we don't know the sign of $x$ and $y$.

$$x<y\iff y>x\iff y-x>0$$

Then we need to show that

$$\frac 1x>\frac 1y \iff \frac 1x-\frac 1y>0\iff \frac{y-x}{xy}>0$$

Thus, we can conclude that,

$$x<y\implies \frac 1x>\frac 1y, \,\,\text{iff}\,\, xy>0.$$